# Android show error when server shifted from http to https

Tags: android, http, https

My live android app stop working when server shifted from http to https.

Tried adding .htaccess for redirecting but still same problem.
i can't change my baseurl at android, but need help to modify at php code.

Answer (score 0):

because android does not understand your serverside configuration so you have to put it manually in an android constant file make for the store base URL and all basic string data so you have not to change everywhere....and save lots of time...also please show your android code ...so anyone can understand where you want to change

Answer (score 0):

Yes... i got the solutions..
you can change http to https without changed android code base url ( which was live with http ) by not forcing to https at cpanel > domains > Force HTTPS Redirect > off

thanks